# Running a R function in background

Tags: r

Hi I have R function which I usually call it from R studio using the below commands

```
source("test.R")

test()
```

This is long running job and I want to run it in background so that even if I logout or close the R studio it will be still running.

Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Comment: Do you need to use RStudio for this? What OS are you using?

Comment: Run it from the command line and [put the job in the background](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0100.php)?

Comment: In Unix from directory where script lives run `Rscript test.R &` from cmd?

Comment: Dason Am running in on Windows OS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the future package (I'm the author) for this, e.g.

```
library("future")
plan(multisession)

# non-blocking
res %<-% test()

something_else()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot HenrikB for your help. It worked fine and saved my time on manual intervention. Thanks again.

Comment: Henrik when I use the future , as soon as I close the R studio will the job stop processing

Comment: I just checked; quitting the main R session will immediately kill multicore futures, whereas if you use multisession futures they will keep until completed.  When you use `plan(multiprocess)`, it equals `plan(multicore)` when you're on Unix / macOS, whereas on Windows it equals `plan(multisession)`.  So, if you wish to keep it running, use explicit `plan(multisession)`.

Comment: Thanks Henrik. Let me try plan(multisession) and update how it went. Thanks a lot for your time on this. Appreciate your help

Comment: Henrik. Is there a command to find the jobs running in background from R studio. Just wanted to check the job is actively running or not.

Comment: You can check if a future is resolved or not by using the `resolved()` function which returns a logical.  That takes a Future object.  When you use `f <- future(test())` you can simply do `resolved(f)`.  If you use `v %<-% test()`, you can do `f <- futureOf(v)` and then `resolved(f)`, or simply `resolved(futureOf(v))`.

Comment: Thanks Henrik.I used the below commands library("future")

plan(multisession)

res %<-% test()

resolved(futureOf(res)) and it returned TRUE. Hopefully it is still executing in the back end. It is running for last 12 hours. I will let you know once the process is completed.