# Asynchronous child process in Windows

Tags: r, windows, parallel-processing

On Windows, the usual methods for parallelization in R (foreach, parLapply) will wait until their workers are all done before allowing the parent process to move on. I would like to start up a child process and NOT wait for it to finish its task before running my other code (running that child process only for its side effects). It seems like this behavior is available through the `mcparallel` function in the parallel package - but not on Windows, because it relies on forking! My job requires me to use Windows, so is there a Windows-friendly way to do this?

Comment: Check out the future package.  I think it has what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) package (I'm the author) supports this in a cross-platform manner.  For example,

```
library("future")
plan(multiprocess)
f1 <- future({ asynchronous code evaluated in the background })
f2 <- future({ some other asynchronous code })
v3 <- my_synchronous_code()
v1 <- value(f1)  # get value of f1 expression - wait if not done
v2 <- value(f2)  # get value of f2 expression - wait if not done
y <- f(v1, v2)
```

or equivalently using the future assignment operator:

```
library("future")
plan(multiprocess)
v1 %<-% { asynchronous code evaluated in the background }
v2 %<-% { some other asynchronous code }
v3 <- my_synchronous_code()
y <- f(v1, v2) # "use" value of v1 and v2 expressions - wait if not done
```

See also [Running a R function in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680172/running-a-r-function-in-background/44714363#44714363)

Comment: This is perfect, and a really useful package in many other ways too. Thanks for the great package!

Comment: Thank you - I am glad you find it useful